# Translation for "Ambient Water"

Tags: translation

A water dispenser provides water at 3 different temperatures:

- chilled water
- **ambient water**
- hot water

What is a suitable and short translation for "ambient water"? This water is served at room temperature.

Correct translations would be "Wasser bei Raum-/Umgebungstemperatur", but that seems a little too long. "Ungekühltes Wasser" is the best solution that I have found so far. Do you have any better ideas?

Comment: gekühlt / ungekühlt / heiß

Comment: I think "Zimmertemperatur" would do the trick.

Comment: lauwarm oder handwarm, je nachdem, wie warm es wirklich ist

Comment: I feel lauwarm and handwarm (maybe 30-35 °C?) are warmer than the typical room temperature (20-22 °C).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, these translations would be best:

•chilled water = kaltes/gekühltes Wasser (gekühlt sounds a bit better)

•ambient water
--> there are multiple possible translations:

- **raumtemperiertes** Wasser (this is an **official word** by producers of water dispensers)
- ungekühltes Wasser (like you already said)
- laues Wasser

•hot water = warmes/heisses Wasser

Hope I could help you.

Comment: Thank you, *raumtemperiert* seems great. Maybe still a Little Long, but straight to the Point, Part of the lingo and usable in many ways.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Suggesting *lauwarm*

Answer (score 6):

If the dispenser looks similar to the ones typically found in offices, I would get rid of "water" at all, since this is obvious. This leaves you with the labels:

- kalt
- normal
- heiß

It is always tricky to state attractively, that one does nothing. So another approach would be to use a totally different term like *frisch*, which should work when looking at the other terms in comparison.

A more international symbolic approach would be to use color-coded bullets:

- blue
- hollow (i. e. a circle) or grey
- red